# LLamar Asp.net WebMetodo usando Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, aplicación-web, asp

Estoy llamando un metodo Asp.Net C# desde un script me funciona perfecto cuando es en la **url:'default.aspx/NombreDelMetodo'** pero cuando entro al proyecto donde lo debo implementar el codigo tengo problemas con la url intente estas tres formas pero  me dan error

```
  url: "@Url.Content('~/Delivery/mapGoogle.aspx/MiMetodo')"
  url: "/Delivery/mapGoogle.aspx/MiMetodo",
  url: "../Delivery/mapGoogle.aspx/MiMetodo",

se ejecuta en mi navegador http://localhost:55531/Delivery/mapGoogle.aspx
```

Micodigo

```
function InvocarMetodoWeb() {
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "@Url.Content('~/Delivery/mapGoogle.aspx/MetodoWeb')",
           data: '{name: "' + 'EFRAIN' + '" }',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: OnSuccess,
           error: function (result) {
               alert("Error" + result);
           }
          });

         }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
           }
```

mi sistema de archivos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error es el que te sale? Te funciona en localhost pero por ejemplo cuando ingresas desde www.pagina.com/tudireccion no?

Comment: Hola ....No e publicado el proyecto ..pero creo que por politica de la empresa no puedo usar www.midominio.com/pagina.aspx/NombreDelMetodo ... debo usar una Url dentro del servidor ?? a menos q esto no sea posible

Comment: Yo estoy trabajando con webmethods y los errores que me salen son por la url o bien porque el webservice esta en la raiz o en una carpeta pero para esto seria de ayuda ver que error te suelta, al estar en el navegador presiona F12 y despues ejecuta esa funcion (al hacer click en el submit, al cargar la pagina o donde quiera que llames a la funcion) y en la consola que se abre al presionar F12 te saldra el error.

Comment: lo que sale en el depurador es esto   typeof JSON!="undefined"&&(window._vwdJSON=JSON),typeof define!="undefined"&&(window._vwdDefine=define,define=null),typeof window.onbeforeunload!="undefined"&&(window._vwdonbeforeunload=window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: agrega lo que falte editanto tu pregunta, así la vas completando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado lo mismo que estás haciendo:

- Utilizar ASP.net MVC y agregar una *CarpetaRandom* donde se encuentra un webform.
- Puedo llamar la funcion desde el mismo webform: `http://localhost:53633/carpetaRandom/Webform.aspx` o desde cualquier otra parte del sistema mediante `AJAX`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="escribe tu nombre" value="" />    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowCurrentTime()">
     llamar al WebMethod 
</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Content("~/CarpetaRandom/WebForm.aspx/GetCurrentTime")',        
            data: '{name: "' + $("#nombre").val() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

En el archivo **WebForm.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {
            return "Saludos " + name + Environment.NewLine + "La hora es: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

Dando como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fino Fredyfx ..pero no entiendo bien donde pasas el parametro del nombre ..que haces alli??

Comment: fredyfx ..no entiendo bien lo que haces cuando pasas el parametro name ?????

Comment: Te refieres al JavaScript o al WebMethod?

Comment: me refiero a esta linea  data: '{name: "' + $("#nombre").val() + '" }', por que  a mi metodo que ya funciona segun tus recomendaciones quiero pasarle un Objeto List y no c como hacerlo??

Comment: Edita la pregunta con la nueva información y edito la respuesta

Comment: Voy a plantear una nueva  pregunta  ...asi esta quedara como referencia para otros con el mismo problema..te parece???

Comment: me parece perfecto; recuerda aceptar las respuestas que se ajusten a lo que preguntaste, así mantenemos la salud del sitio :D